# Google HTTP/S Load Balancing Health Criteria

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-http-load-balancer

If my health checks always return 200, but my backends return a bunch of 5xx's to GLB for actual load-balanced requests, will my backends be considered unhealthy to GLB? My experience seems to say "yes," but I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: Details depend on the type of health check but 200 is expected. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks

Comment: Right, my health checks are 200s but the actual load-balanced resources served by my back-ends give all kinds of response codes. Wondering if i need to avoid serving certain 5xx codes to keep backends healthy.

Comment: Review what 5xx errors mean. To the load balancer, your backend service is failing.

Comment: Your health check doesn't test in a correct manner your app. Your health check shoud receive 5XX if your app serve 5XX

Comment: Just to circle back on these comments. Imagine an API service that is healthy but one of your biggest customers starts sending spikes of requests whose input exercises a server bug you didn't know existed. Those requests produce HTTP 5xx while the long tail of your other customers are using the service without issue. You may be temporarily serving a large fraction of 5xx's, but you do *not* want the service to be taken out of the load balancer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went to GCP support. They told me that your backend can return 5xx's all day, and as long as the health check returns 200, the load balancer will consider your backend healthy.